# Android studio strange behaviour : file gets locked unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am experiencing strange behavior with Android Studio for a few days.
I am not able to write/open or do anything with some file(in which I am just working) unexpectedly.
For that, I have to restart android studio, and then after I am able to edit it.

I want to know if there is any other solution to get my files back in working mode without closing and opening an android studio.
My current Android studio version: 4.1.2

Comment: I am also facing same issue .